# Error in Django Password Reset: Not getting the NorReverseMatch Error

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am working with Django 3.0, and I am using Atom as my editor, to do password reset in django i am not getting the error NoReverseMatch when i did not pass the password_reset_confirm route in urlpattern.
Instead after going to password-reset template I am getting redirect to password-reset/done template with no error, and i am not receiving any mail, can anyone tell why am i not getting that error even though i did not mention the path for password_reset_confirm route.

```
my urlpattern =[
    path('password-reset/',
          auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name="users/password_reset.html"),
          name="password_reset"),
    path('password-reset/done/',
          auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name="users/password_reset_done.html"),
          name="password_reset_done"),
]
```

Can anyone please tell why am I not getting the error?

Comment: When you say "I am not receiving any email" how do you check that? It sounds like you're on development, what did you configure your `EMAIL_BACKEND` to be in your settings?

Comment: @dirkgroten EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

Comment: AFAIK the email will be sent if the user with the email address submitted exists in the db and the user is active. It will not give any errors if that's not the case, it'll just say the email was sent even if no email was sent. Are you sure you're entering an email address that corresponds to an active user?

Comment: Also, how does your `password_reset_email.html` template look like? That's the only place where the url for the reset token is created.

Comment: @dirkgroten I am following a youtube tutorial by Corey Schafer.Here's the link to the video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-tyBEsHSv7w&list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p&index=13&t=789s , I did not made any changes to password_reset_email template , it was default. And in the video error displayed at 7:56 is the error I am not getting, and I guess this is the reason for improper wroking of my code. I am not understanding why am i not getting  this error. Please if you could refer to it.

Comment: @dirkgroten, thanks the email i was trying was not registerd with db, it was my mistake, thanks again